# Error 'no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable ' en Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

```
PS C:\Users\Usuario\PycharmProjects\RobotFrame_Nivel_Uno> cd.\Test_Case\
cd.\Test_Case\ : El término 'cd.\Test_Case\' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si 
escribió correctamente el nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
    
+ cd.\Test_Case\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (cd.\Test_Case\:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: El error te indica que no se reconoce, porque como menciona @Candid-Moe, lo estás escribiendo mal! en vez de `cd` y luego el destino `.\Test_Case`, estás usando un comando que no existe `cd.\Test_Case`, como si pones `ls-l` en vez de poner `ls -l `.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta un espacio entre el comando "cd" y su argumento ".\Test_Case". El comando sería `cd .\Test_Case`.